# Determine Azure IP Address of appService, blob and general storage

Tags: azure, url

I have a url as below from Azure Portal
https://qwergeneralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sqldb/DBNAME-Test.bacpac?sp=r&st=2018-07-11T02:12:52Z&se=2018-07-13T08:12:52Z&spr=https&sv=2017-11-09&sig=%2FYrtyuZtl5eJdfj07mTtKjbol8J9d1%2thyuJ%klemhg%3D&sr=b

How can I determine the IP address from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the IP Address, you could use `cmd` to ping the url host name.

[image]

But you **need to note** that the IP Address changes every week. You could download the `xml` file in this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653), then check the IP Address range of different regions in the file.

> **Details**
>
> This file contains the IP address ranges (including Compute, SQL and Storage ranges) used in the Microsoft Azure Datacenters. An updated file is posted weekly which reflects the currently deployed ranges and any upcoming changes to the IP ranges. New ranges appearing in the file will not be used in the datacenters for at least one week. Please download the new xml file every week and perform the necessary changes on your site to correctly identify services running in Azure.

Comment: @cell Yes，always timeout.

Comment: The xml file is now marked as deprecated, I believe the json file at this link is the latest list https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519