# Get Public IP for the Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted my web application and the server for it. However I will like to know if Azure Web App has an Public IP that can accessed via internet or it is only available via the azure portal?

**Update**

The ip from the ping command or from custom domain. I think they are the virtual IP addresses and not public ip address.

Answer (score 4):

You could ping your web app URL in `cmd`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However when I put that IP on the browser and hit enter, it says Web Site not found

Comment: @User1911 The IP means `Azure Datacenter IP Ranges`, you could not access it directly, you could refer to this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299649/determine-azure-ip-address-of-appservice-blob-and-general-storage/51301207#51301207) for more details.

Comment: @User1911 there lives a lot of apps on one public ip. the server routing the http requests distinguish between them using Host part of http header. It's called "name-based virtual hosting", more on https://superuser.com/questions/577070/is-it-possible-for-many-domain-names-to-share-one-ip-address/577072#577072

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Web App has an Public IP that is accessible via the internet. You can find the IP within the **Custom domains** blade:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However when I put that IP on the browser and hit enter, it says Web Site not found.

Comment: Of course. The IP address is shared among other apps. The servers there rely on the Host header to map the request to the correct app.

Comment: Thats right, you can use this IP to configure an A record but you wont be able to go to your app by that ip (since the IP is shared with other web apps)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for the next one reading.

Go to Settings/Properties, there you will find a list of Outbound IP addresses.

And if you are running Premium V2, check also the Additional Outbound IP addresses.